# StructureMap auto registration of generic types that are not referenced

Tags: c#, structuremap, auto-registration

I am getting this error: `No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily IReadModelRepository`

This is my registry

```
    public class DependencyRegistry : Registry
    {
        public DependencyRegistry()
        {
            //Must reference ReadModelRepository dll or get the above error
            //For(typeof(IReadModelRepository<>)).Use(typeof(ReadModelRepository<>));

            Scan(x =>
            {
                x.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
                x.WithDefaultConventions();
            });
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to get the above registry working without the explicit reference to the `ReadModelRepository`?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to avoid that ?

Comment: The auto registration will bind IType to Type automagically, and then there's the IRepository, which has to have a manual bind. That means that there is something I'm not understanding about StructureMap and the conventions are no longer consistent.